How can I filter a list of dictionaries based on multiple key conditions in Python?
I am working with a list of dictionaries in Phython and I am trying to filter out items that meet specific conditions across multiple keys. I have the following list:
data = [
    {"name": "Atif", "age": 25, "city": "Delhi"},
    {"name": "Shahid", "age": 30, "city": "Gujrat"},
    {"name": "Soumya", "age": 25, "city": "Bihar"},
    {"name": "Rounak", "age": 22, "city": "Delhi"}
]

I want to filter this list to get only the entries where age is 25 and city is "Delhi". I have tried using list comprehension, but I am struggling to apply multiple conditions efficiently. Could anyone suggest a Pythonic way to do this?
filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry["age"] == 25]
I had used this method to filter out.

This question is similar to: Is there a way to use two if conditions in list comprehensions in python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry["age"] == 25 and entry["city"] == 'Delhi']


data = [
    {"name": "Atif", "age": 25, "city": "Delhi"},
    {"name": "Shahid", "age": 30, "city": "Gujrat"},
    {"name": "Soumya", "age": 25, "city": "Bihar"},
    {"name": "Rounak", "age": 22, "city": "Delhi"}
]

filtered_data = [entry for entry in data if entry["age"] == 25 and entry["city"] == "Delhi"]

print(filtered_data)

Your output will be
[{'name': 'Atif', 'age': 25, 'city': 'Delhi'}]

